# What did Dumbledore mean by "[Harry's] party"?

Tags: harry-potter

After reading Deathly Hallows one doubt remained with me. In the chapter King's Cross, there is this dialogue between Harry and Dumbledore.

> “Well, where do you think we are?” asked Harry, a little defensively.
>
> “My dear boy, I have no idea. This is, as they say, your party.”

Actually, this was the only thing that didn't make sense to me. What did Dumbledore mean by 'his party'?

Comment: It's a figure of speech.  You might want to try asking on the English Language Learners site, they may be able to explain it more clearly than we could.

Comment: @Harry Johnston Ok thanks.. I did not think that it was a figure of speech..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He meant Harry was in control of the situation, and could choose to live or die. After Dumbledore says this Harry asks him "Tell me one last thing, is this real? Or has this been happening inside my head?" and Dumbledore replies "Of course it is happening in your head, Harry. But why on earth should that mean it isn't real?"

This begs the question if it was actually Dumbledore's spirit talking to Harry, or just a figment of Harry's mind taking Dumbledore's form to speak wisdom to him, but either way, this was inside Harry's mind, therefore he's in control. It is, so to speak, his party.